# Boot goes to initramfs

Tags: grub2, initramfs

I installed Ubuntu on my machine as a duel boot on a hdd in a drive caddy on a Lenovo w510. On my primary ssd I have windows 8. I believe that my grub install is located on my primary drive. When I boot into Ubuntu from grub a go into initramfs imidiatly. I have never be able to boot into this installation yet. I can boot from a live USB still.I get:

> Missing modules
>
> ALERT! /Dev/disk/by-uuid/........ does not exist.

I used boot-repair and it didn't work

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10644547/

Also when I select this second drive from bios, I get no boot at all.

Comment: run boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: First of all, boot from a live cd/usb and backup all your data.

Comment: I'm not concerned with backing up. I've also tried re-installing Ubuntu to the drive multiple times. Its never booted up, so i have no files to be concerned about.